# Android Emulator runs different OS (6.0) than the one specified in AVD (11.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I setup a new emulator (AVD) in Android Studio, targeting the Android 11 OS (API 30).

See image here:
[image]

However, when I run the emulator, the Android version shows 6.0 and it is a vey old UI with very old capabilities. See image here:

[image]

I cannot understand what I should change or what I am doing wrong.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the problem limited to the "Google APIs" image? If you create an AVD for Android 11 with one of the other images, do you get the same result?

Comment: @CommonsWare Indeed the Android 10 emulator (1st in screenshot) works as expected, it loads an Android 10 version. Any reason why the Android 11 (Google APIs) is created with Android 6 instead? Thanks.

Comment: If you create an AVD for **Android 11** with one of the other images (e.g., the "Google Play" image, or the image without any Google APIs), do you get the same result?

Comment: I could not find a "Google Play" image, it was only either with "APIs" or not.

Comment: I did install Android 10, with APIs, this seems to load Android 10 indeed, so this works. Not sure why Android 11 with APIs does not work and shows Android 6.0 instead.

Comment: Same with Google Play (found it), it works. The only problem now is the CTRL-M in a react native app is not triggered because CTRL immediately triggers the ZOOM/UNZOOM mode.